# How to download audio file from playlist?

Tags: html

I have a playlist of audio files with a play button on the left and download button on the right. When you press the download button it just plays the audio file and doesn't download the file. Why won't the file download?

Here is my audio playlist with download button (just showing 1 audio file for simplicity):

```
                   <ol class="playlist">
                       <li>
                          <div class="as-link" data-src="/mp3/Ethereum.wav">
                             <!--Row-->
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 ">
                                   <div class="block-track">
                                      <h6 class="mb-0 opc-70 uppercase">Ethereum</h6>
                                      <span>Steffi Blümchen </span>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-md-right">
                                   <a href="/mp3/Ethereum.wav" download="true" class="btn-s uppercase btn btn-primary with-ico" ><i class="icon-download"></i>Download</a>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </li>

                   </ol>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you ready to use javascript, you can try this code.

**Your html**

```
<ol class="playlist">
                       <li>
                          <div class="as-link" data-src="/mp3/Ethereum.wav">
                             <!--Row-->
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 ">
                                   <div class="block-track">
                                      <h6 class="mb-0 opc-70 uppercase">Ethereum</h6>
                                      <span>Steffi Blümchen </span>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-md-right">
                                   <a href="#" onclick="download('/mp3/Ethereum.wav')" download="true" class="btn-s uppercase btn btn-primary with-ico" ><i class="icon-download"></i>Download</a>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </li>

                   </ol>
```

**Script For Download**

```
<script>
function download( filename) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = filename;
  a.setAttribute("download", filename);
  var b = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  b.initEvent("click", false, true);
  a.dispatchEvent(b);
  return false;
}

download("a.mp3");
</script>
```